# Unity dialogue import

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dialog, unity3d-gui

I'm trying to import my dialog into Unity 5. Is there some kind of default Unity function to do that? For example, importing all the dialogue from an outside source like Word, or Notepad++, and assigning it directly to all the characters interactions. Currently there is a LOT of dialogue. I wrote a script in C# that lets you add the dialog into Unity but you have to write every possible Question, Answer, Interaction, Cutscene_Dialogue etc., into the forms manually. Is there some default Unity plugin available to use that lets me assign all of the conversations to the characters? I'm currently using Unity 5 free edition.

The game is not RPG, it's a Point & Click adventure, can the RPG dialogue logic be applied all the same?  I found the [Dialog XML importer](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/8289) and [Dialogue System for Unity](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/11672) in the asset store, looks like they would do the trick, as they simplify the process, I just want to know if theres a a custom solution for importing without the need to buy an asset or typing manually all of the interaction in the boxes.

Comment: Please, don't use `unity` tag for questions related to Unity game engine.

Comment: Can you establish what the `dialog` is in the scope of this question? Do I understand correctly that this is some text, structured with some sort of format, that represents some sort of NPC-player dialogs? What's the format? And what exactly do you want the "import" action to accomplish?

Comment: Yes you are correct. The `dialog` would be NPC-PC interaction, with a structure like  one for example http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Dialog_tree_example.svg/399px-Dialog_tree_example.svg.png I want to import the whole thing, from i.e. Notepad++ into Unity and assign every piece of dialogue to each scenes/character_interactions. Oh and I'm using Unity2D for the game

Comment: Well, this sounds awfully broad to be a question on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just write your own XML file and import it, you don't need an asset for that. In the XML file you can have an attribute in the header of each dialog to be able to define who should say what.
[The XML document class can help with that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [be used to load the file too.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)